# Record Type not found

Tags: salesforce

There is a record type in Account that I can see while I do SOQL in records but when I go to setup > object > record type. I am not able to find any such record type. Where else can I find the record types for account? I can also see this record type in Profiles level, but not in Layout assignments. I have checked the API and UI name properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have person accounts enabled? It's probably one of these. In your SOQL go `SELECT Id, Name, RecordType.Name, IsPersonAccount FROM Account WHERE Id = ...`

What's your UI? In Lightning you should see all types on Account page (/lightning/setup/ObjectManager/Account/RecordTypes/view). In Classic it's a separate menu:

[image: classic setup showing business/person account types sidebar menu]

Comment: YEs, I have person accounts enabled and its person account record. So how do I modify the layouts?

Comment: I am checking it in lightning.

Comment: Setup -> Object Manager -> Person Account -> page layouts (/lightning/setup/ObjectManager/PersonAccount/PageLayouts/view). It looks bit weird they pretend it's a separate table but well... Technically Task/Event/Activity is bit of a mess in same table too I guess

Comment: Thanks for responding, I switched to classic and did Edit Layout from record page at that time.  In lighting, I guess this is the way.